# PHP post and comment is not showing in group

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get posts and its comments,but it always keep showing post duplicated with one comment each time   **please see image**

[image]

this is what I've tried

test.php

```
$q = "SELECT posts.*, comments.*
      FROM posts
      LEFT JOIN comments
      ON comments.postid= posts.postid ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $q);

while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<h5>".$fetch['post']."</h5>";
    echo "<p><i class='fa fa-user'></i> ".$fetch['comment']."</p>";
    echo "<textarea class='form-control' name = 'comment' placeholder='Write Comment'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-lg' value='Add Comment!'>";    
}
```

and this is mydatabase

[image]
[image]

**what I'm trying to do is to show all comment related to it post, but not working**

I've try this function its working but its not showing first comment, always start from second comment

functions.php

```
function getPostsInfoo(){
$q = "SELECT posts.*, comments.*
     FROM posts
     LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.postid=posts.postid";
$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
$posts = [];
while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if(isset($posts[$fetch["postid"]])){
        $posts[$fetch["id_cmnt"]]["comment"][] = [
            "username" => $fetch["username"],
            "comment" => $fetch["comment"],
            "cmntdate" => $fetch["cmntdate"]
        ];
        echo "<p><a href='#'> ".$fetch["username"]."</a> ".$fetch["comment"]."</p>";
    }else{
        $posts[$fetch["postid"]] = [
            "post" => $fetch["post"],
            "username" => $fetch["username"],
            "comment" => [[
                "username" => $fetch["username"],
                "comment" => $fetch["comment"],
                "cmntdate" => $fetch["cmntdate"]
            ]]
        ];
        echo "<p ><a href='#'>".$fetch["username"]."</a>".$fetch["post"]."</p>";
    }
}
return $posts;

}
```

test.php

`$database->getPostsInfoo();`  I've only add this and it worked but see the results

[image]

Comment: first code is showing all post and comments but not in right way

Comment: second code (function I've tried) is showing the right way but with missing first comment

Comment: any ideas ?....

Comment: Shouldn't `$posts[$fetch["id_cmnt"]]["comment"][]` be `$posts[$fetch["postid"]]["comment"][]`?

Comment: @El_Vanja I've try to change like you suggest but it still not showing first comment

Comment: what is the problem ? why is first comment is not showing

Comment: Ah. Because in `else` you only echo the post. You should echo the post and comment. Though, it's a bit strange that you echo while building your posts array. You should rather build the array and then create html based on the array.

Comment: @El_Vanja is there any easy way or any solution that you can show me and I'll modify the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution

```
$q = "SELECT posts.*, comments.*
      FROM posts
      LEFT JOIN comments
      ON comments.postid= posts.postid ";

      $result = mysqli_query($this->connection,$q);
      $previous_post = 0;
      while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
           if ($previous_post != $data['postid']) {
               echo '<h1>' . $data['post'] . '</h1>';
                $previous_post = $data['postid'];
           }
           echo '<p>' . $data['comment'] . '</p>';
      }
```